# Can we implement Mirai on a closed network (i.e., without access to Internet) on Raspberry Pi's?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Note: This is only for research purposes.

I wish to run a Mirai attack using 3 Raspberry Pi's all connected across an Ethernet switch.
I plan to run the CNC on the first Raspberry Pi, the bot on the second Raspberry Pi and the victim is the third Raspberry Pi.

Any help regarding how I can go about passing signals to the bot from the CNC if I can't use Internet access for the bots to get the commands by repeatedly pinging a URL and somehow instead ask the local IP of the CNC server for commands?

Thanks in advance!